# Tor can no longer access specific web site - Conneciton Timed out!

Tags: connection

I am using the latest version (10.0.11) of the TOR browser and up until a few days ago, had no problems. Now I seem unable to access a specific website (that I can access via a standard browser.) The website is "http://dl.free.fr/".

When trying to access the site using TOR I get .. "The connection has timed out..". I have tried clearing the browser cache, I also dis-connected my VPN and still cannot connect to the site. AS I mentioned earlier, I can access the site ok with any other browser.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Some websites block Tor users, and it's possible that this website might be too.

Comment: DL.free has starting blocking tor exit sites. You will need to use a proxy to circumvent.

Comment: You can use good proxy server:
https://www.sslsecureproxy.com/
https://hidester.com/proxy/
https://www.filterbypass.me/
https://onlineproxy.eu/
https://www.zalmos.com/